# Issues with Jenkins installation

Tags: macos, jenkins, installation

I recently had an issue with Jenkins, where my scripts were failing.
When i went back today i found myself logged out from Jenkins and it once again asked me for the initial password from the secrets folder.

I couldnt locate this and deleted jenkins from my laptop.
I have tried reinstalling everything and when i try to set it up again, i once again cannot find the secrets folder.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

I am running on a mac and everything is up to date.
Java is 8.231.

The steps i did was.

1. Download jenkins 2.206
2. Install
3. It says "go to /Users/Eamon/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword"
4. This folder doesnt exist but in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home there still is not folder for initial password.

But there is a "failedBoot.txt" file that keeps incrementing and adding timestamps to it as time goes by.

I dont understand how i had no issue when installing this last week for the first time.

Please someone point me in a better direction!

Comment: it seems that jenkins team people deprecated the OS X installer, they are instead suggesting to use `brew` package manager to install jenkins. It is not going to install the most recent version though. https://jenkins.io/download/weekly/macos/

Comment: Hey thanks Dennis. I figured out that if i run this command in terminal i can access the "Temporary secret password" required in order to finish installation :

sudo cat /Users/YourUser/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword;

That gives you the password and you can copy and paste it where required. Still having other issues but its strange how it worked peacefully until today.

Answer (score 0):

As i said, for some reason when i re-downloaded Jenkins i couldnt locate any files in the path specified by the installer.

Run this command in terminal i can access the "Temporary secret password" required in order to finish installation : sudo cat /Users/YourUser/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

That gave me the password required to continue installation.